# Assigning value to a model in a handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm following [this](https://yoember.com/) tutorial and any time it references an input element it defines them as so:

```
{{input type="text action='actionname'... }}
```

I'm told this is out of date and indeed the docs don't [use that format](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/), instead using this format:

```
<input type="text" {{action 'actionname' ... }}
```

I'm at the point of the tutorial where I'm saving data to the store. I've amended the tutorial to use angle brackets instead of curly braces like so:

```
<input type="text" value={{model.name}} class="form-control" placeholder="The name of the Library" />
<input type="text" value={{model.address}} class="form-control" placeholder="The address of the Library" />
<input type="text" value={{model.phone}} class="form-control" placeholder="The phone number of the Library" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" {{action 'saveLibrary' model}}>Add to library list</button>
```

My route looks like:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({

  model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('library');
  },

  actions: {
    saveLibrary(newLibrary) {
      newLibrary.save().then(() => this.transitionTo('libraries'));
    },

    willTransition() {
      this.controller.get('model').rollbackAttributes();
    }
  }

});
```

When I call the route action `saveLibrary` and open the debugger, `newLibrary` doesn't have any data from the model properties. Whenever I change the handlebars template to use curly braces like the tutorial, it works fine; newLibrary contains `name`, `address` & `phone`.

What is the syntax for using angle brankets and having it propagate to `route.js`?

Answer (score 3):

The angle bracket component should be `<Input>` not `<input>`.

Comment: Why is it `<input>` in the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/input-helpers/)?

Comment: it's lower case for curly bracket invocation, and upper case for angle bracket invocation

Comment: Much of the octane stuff is to be released, but can be previewed here:  https://emberjs.com/editions/octane/